# Black MacBook Webcam not working

Tags: 11.10, webcam, macbook, apple

I have a 2006 13 inch macbook that I put Ubuntu on after buying a new hard drive. Everything is working great, however, I can't seem to get the webcam to work. I was pretty sure I'm missing a driver for it, but when I looked into it, it looked like the driver was already there. Maybe the file got corrupted or something? Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 2):

Apple iSight webcams require special firmware. Install the `isight-firmware-tools` package, and follow it's instructions.

There's some more documentation on that here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleiSight

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `cheese` from the Software Center and seeing if that works. If it doesn't work, your problem could be driver related. If it does work then you'll know that your next troubleshooting step will be with the configuration of whatever software you're trying to use. Flash is known to be problematic when it comes to webcams, for instance (in my experience at least).

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting